# how to speedup loading the pics from mysql in perl

Tags: jquery, mysql, perl

i use the code below to retrieve a particular pic attached with an id. Hence to retrieve say 10 pics i need to call the code ten times. It is very slow even to load a small no of(10) pics.

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
$query = new CGI();
$idpic = $query->param("sn");

my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=pics;host=localhost","root","xxxxxxx");

$query = "select itemid, image, price from veg where itemid = $idpic";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $idpic = $data[0];
    $img = $data[1];
    print STDOUT "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n";
    print STDOUT "Content-length: \n\n";
    binmode STDOUT;
    print STDOUT $img;
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

I used the Lazyload jquery plugin.But it made the speed to even slowdown.

Is there any better way to retrieve images from mysql. Is there any trick which makes speed similar to that of retrieving from a flat file.

Comment: Have them cached on hard disk.

Comment: Do you mean storing the pics in a local folder and then retrieving them?

Comment: is there any reason why you store the images in the database and not only metadata from those images?

Comment: @navin yes, but store them in local folder in separate thread (cron job/etc..)

Comment: i found it easy to manage and organize my data all at one place and moreover i dont know how to match the pics with their metadata

Comment: You must always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of *every* Perl program you write, especially when you are asking others for help with fixing it. It would also be poilte if you would add some indentation and whitespace so that your code is at least readable.

Comment: i will keep them in mind

Comment: Second what Borodin already said about `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Also, you [`use placeholders`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) or you're opening yourself up to a sql injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you might have is the amount of data you are storing for each image in the database.
Without knowing how big they are, its difficult to give any advice on why it is slow.

One solution might be that when adding those images to your database, you fetch metadata with some libraries (such as dimensions, file size, no of colors, hash value, etc...) for those images.
When storing this information to the database you could use the filename/directory name as a key and simply add more columns for the rest of the data.

When fetching the images you get the filename/directory and can send it directly from filesystem.

Comment: sorry for not having mentioned the size of the pics. They were just 10-15 kb only. I didnt get the point your refering to

Comment: The point i was trying to make clear is that i would not save the image data in the database but instead as files in your file system. This helps keeping your database small and fast and easier to backup.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHI, or other file caching module: load the images from db once, cache, then serve from the cache. If the images are small you can use Memcached too.

Consider using a persistent Perl application (using a plain Plack/PSGI microframework or frameworks such as Dancer, Mojolicious or Catalyst) if you can and if you're not limited to shared hosting.

The problem might be some place else: the client is loading 10 images one after the other; you should consider using image sprites.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from answers already given, there are myriad things to be done to speed up your program: caching, image sprites, using the static files instead of the DB, using a persistent web service instead of CGI, etc.

But you neglected to provide any timing information. Have you pulled up the developer tools in your browser, and used the network tab to get real values.

You might find that you have bad DNS resolution.

You might try logging the amount of time it takes to get the data from the DB, and the start and end times of the program.  You might find that it's out network latency, or you might a database problem - your blobs could be stored in poorly by the DB, or the OS.

SO lots to go on, but you'll need something measurable, so you can determine if any changes you make to code or configuration actually make a difference.